# What are some technical reasons for not including N-ary multiplication in the SQL standard?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

If I want to *add up two* values in a query, I can use the `+` operator.
If I want to sum up all values returned by a query, I can use `SUM`.

If I want to *multiply two* values in a query, I can use the `*` operator.
If, however, I want to multiply together all values returned by a query, **there does not appear to be a `MULT` or `PRODUCT` or the like**.

I find myself using `exp(sum(ln(X)))`, which is ridiculous. It's astonishing that this feature is not present since even more "esoteric" things like covariances and regression coefficients are conveniently available in some dialects.

Why is it that the SQL standard does not have this (I believe) "basic" feature? Surely it must be a conscious design decision. Are there any technical advantages to not having this operation or discouraging users from performing multiplication on large query results?

Comment: *Why* is opinion based, and will probably be closed as off-topic. For a solution, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156055/product-aggregate-in-postgresql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623282/multiplynum-aggregate-function-in-postgresql

Comment: Because it's not part of the SQL standard, may be?

Comment: @Colin'tHart, don't think that design decisions such as this are opinion-based; there are technical reasons for and against implementing a specific feature. What I am looking for is technical reasons why a product function was not implemented in PostgreSQL by the developers.

Comment: @mustaccio, in that case, the question should be why it is not part of the SQL standard, will change it accordingly.

Comment: Just as an aside, the `exp(sum(ln(x)))` only works if X is always positive. You probably will need to change it to `case when sum(case when X < 0 then 1 end)%2=0 then -1 else 1 end*exp(sum(ln(abs(X))))` for safety purposes.

Comment: you can use `bool_and` if you constraint the inputs to 0 or 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the PostgreSQL core team has spent days deciding that this should *not* be included in core.

Seriously:

- a `mul` operator is not in the SQL standard.
- With PostgreSQL's extensibility, it is trivial to define such an aggregate function yourself:

  ```
  CREATE AGGREGATE mul(integer) (
     SFUNC = int4mul,
     STYPE = integer,
     INITCOND = '1'
  );
  ```